# Two Android Studios in one PC

Tags: android-studio

I have two `Android Studio` versions on my Windows PC - newest and old one. I would like to separate them as much as possible in order they had no possibility corrupt each other files. I have downloaded and unzipped old version `Android Studio` into separate folder and it works fine.

I noticed that both studios are using same folder C:\Users\user_name.android . Is it possible somehow to tell `Android Studio` specific path to `.android` folder.